# Arreglar Notice: Undefined variable y Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: php

Mi código .php es:

```
<?php
$Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$Apellidos = $_POST['Apellidos'];
$Alias = $_POST['Alias'];
$Correo = $_POST['Correo'];
$Ingreso = $_POST['Ingreso'];
$Pais = $_POST['Pais'];
$Estado = $_POST['Estado'];
$Ciudad = $_POST['Ciudad'];
$destinario = "KariTereViaAlEco192@outlook.com";
$asunto = "Registro de guardián";
$carta = "Nombre(s): $Nombre \n"; 
$carta .= "Apellidos: $Apellidos\n";
$carta .= "Alias: $Alias\n";
$carta .= "Correo electronico: $Correo\n";
$carta .= "Pais: $Pais\n";
$carta .= "Estado: $Estado\n";
$carta .= "Ciudad: $Ciudad";
mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta);
 header('registroenviado.html');
?>
```

Pero al enviar, salen estos errores.

> Notice: Undefined variable: destinatario in /storage/ssd3/936/5718936/public_html/enviar.php on line 20
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd3/936/5718936/public_html/enviar.php:20) in /storage/ssd3/936/5718936/public_html/enviar.php on line 21

Comment: Tienes un typo en tu variable $destinatario.  Porque envias la misma informacion dos veces?

Comment: Disculpa, soy principiante de la plataforma y pegué la información dos veces

Comment: intenta mover tu `header('registroenviado.html')` al principio

Comment: Si es como supongo, que una vez enviado el mensaje quieres hacer una redirección, te falta `Location`, deberías ponerlo así: **`header("Location: /registroenviado.html");`** ([ver al respecto la documentación sobre `header`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)). También deberías evaluar el resultado de la ejecución de `mail`, para controlar los errores de envío y mostrar un mensaje adecuado.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tu has declarado tu variable `$destinario` en:

```
$destinario = "KariTereViaAlEco192@outlook.com";
```

y estás llamando a la variable `$destinatario`

```
mail($destinatario, $asunto, $carta);
 header('registroenviado.html');
?>
```

Sólo es un error de tipeo,

---

Respecto al segundo error:

- Comprueba que no hay una línea, espacio en blanco, texto, HTML o
  cualquier otro tipo de contenido antes de la etiqueta
- Comprueba que tampoco hay salida de información antes del uso de
  funciones como setcookie(), header() o cualquier otra función que
  genere o modifique las cabeceras HTTP.

Comment: Ese es uno de los problemas

Comment: Hay dos errores, el primero es Undefined variable y el segundo Cannot modify header information

Comment: Si ya lo note XD